# flutter: when are const widgets rebuilt?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently reading the example code of the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-example-tab-) package:

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;
  int get count => _count;

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Counter>(
        builder: (context, counter, _) {
          return MaterialApp(
            supportedLocales: const [Locale('en')],
            localizationsDelegates: [
              DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              _ExampleLocalizationsDelegate(counter.count),
            ],
            home: const MyHomePage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleLocalizations {
  static ExampleLocalizations of(BuildContext context) =>
      Localizations.of<ExampleLocalizations>(context, ExampleLocalizations);

  const ExampleLocalizations(this._count);

  final int _count;

  String get title => 'Tapped $_count times';
}

class _ExampleLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<ExampleLocalizations> {
  const _ExampleLocalizationsDelegate(this.count);

  final int count;

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => locale.languageCode == 'en';

  @override
  Future<ExampleLocalizations> load(Locale locale) =>
      SynchronousFuture(ExampleLocalizations(count));

  @override
  bool shouldReload(_ExampleLocalizationsDelegate old) => old.count != count;
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Title()),
      body: const Center(child: CounterLabel()),
      floatingActionButton: const IncrementCounterButton(),
    );
  }
}

class IncrementCounterButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const IncrementCounterButton({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: Provider.of<Counter>(context).increment,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }
}

class CounterLabel extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterLabel({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context);
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times:',
        ),
        Text(
          '${counter.count}',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Title extends StatelessWidget {
  const Title({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(ExampleLocalizations.of(context).title);
  }
}
```

At first I was confused to see the following code. It is a MultiProvider, immediately followed by a Consumer, at the top of the Widget tree:

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_)=>Counter()),
  ],
  child: Consumer<Counter>(
    builder: (context, counter, _){
      return MaterialApp(
        home: const MyHomePage()
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

I was wondering: Isn't this really bad for performance?
Everytime the state of the consumer is updated, all the tree has to be rebuilt.
Then I realized the `const` qualifiers everywhere. This seems like a very neat setup.
I decided to debug through it and see when and where widgets are rebuilt.

When the app is first started, flutter goes down the tree and builds the widgets one by one. This makes sense.

When the button is clicked and the `Counter` is incremented, `builder` is called on the Consumer at the very top of the tree. After that, `build` is called on `CounterLabel` and `IncrementCounterButton`.

`CounterLabel` makes sense. This is not `const` and will actually change its content.
But `IncrementCounterButton` is marked as `const`. Why does it rebuild?

It is not clear to me why some `const` widgets are rebuilt while others aren't. What is the system behind this?

Comment: CounterLabel is a const, too. In the example it's wrapped into a const Center. So using dart 2.0, CounterLabel is implicitly declared as const.

Comment: it's wrapped in a const Center() but the CounterLabel itself is not marked const

Comment: It is implicit. `const Center(child: new CounterLabel())` won't compile. The `const` keyword is infered, and the example is just syntax sugar for `const Center(child: const CounterLabel())`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most common reasons for a widget to rebuild are:

- It's parent rebuilt (whatever the reason is)
- Element.markNeedsBuild have been called manually  (typically using setState)
- An inherited widget it depends on updated

Const instance of widgets are immune to the first reason, but they are still affected by the two others.

This means that a const instance of a StatelessWidget will rebuild *only* if one of the inherited widget it uses update.

Comment: Inside the IncrementCounterButton, we are using a FloatingActionButton. This depends on the Counter and uses its increment method. So it would make sense that this dependency is somehow discovered and the FloatingActionButton rebuilds. But as far as I can see, the IncrementCounterButton uses no inherited widget itself.

Comment: (btw I'm the author of this example) `IncrementCounterButton` does use an InheritedWidget. It calls `Provider.of<Counter>(context)`

Comment: ah, that's the explanation then. Thanks.
How is this dependency discovered?
I guess the context of IncrementCounterButton is modified within the call to Provider.of() ?

Would it be possible to get rid of this dependency?

Comment: Do you mind making an independent question or an issue on provider? It's technically unrelated to this question

Answer (score 1):

Provider is a convenient wrapper for InheritedWidget with a lot of nice things done for you.

Because `IncrementCounterButton` accesses Provider (and InheritedWidget under the hood), it listens and rebuilds whenever the data changes.

To prevent buttons or other widgets that do not need to be rebuild on data change, set `listen` to `false`.

> Provider.of(context, listen: false).increment

The caveat is that if the root widget rebuilds, widgets marked with `listen: false` will still rebuild. [Understand how listen: false works when used with Provider<SomeType>.of(context, listen: false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584334/understand-how-listen-false-works-when-used-with-providersometype-ofcontext)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @RayLi and @Remi's answers, another way to prevent a rebuild is to make this modification:

```dart
//       onPressed: Provider.of<Counter>(context).increment,  // This listens
      onPressed: context.read<Counter>().increment,     // this doesn't listen
```

`context.read()` won't update, but in this case this is what you want. `onPressed` will be mapped to the same instance of `.increment` throughout the FloatingActionButton's existence.

`context.read<Counter>()` has the same behavior as `Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false)`.  See [Is Provider.of(context, listen: false) equivalent to context.read()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257064/is-provider-ofcontext-listen-false-equivalent-to-context-read)