# Understand how listen: false works when used with Provider<SomeType>.of(context, listen: false)

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm working through understanding how the Provider package works with Flutter but confused on how listen:false works.

I wrote some basic code using the usual Counter example from a new Flutter project. I created three types of stateless widgets each using a Provider:

1. Provider.of(context)
2. Consumer
3. Provider.of(context, listen: false)

The third example was to show how access the provider object and call methods on it without it rebuilding.

When I run the application all of the widget counts are changing - and I only expect it to change in the first two.

This is a simple example - what am I doing wrong?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;
  int get count => _count;

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Provider Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Provider Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Counter counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ExampleProviderWidget(),
            ExampleConsumerWidget(),
            ExampleNoListenWidget()
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => counter.increment(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleProviderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Counter counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context);

    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Provider.of<Counter>(context):',
            ),
            Text(
              '${counter.count}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleConsumerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Counter>(
      builder: (context, counter, _) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Consumer<Counter>(context):',
                ),
                Text(
                  '${counter.count}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ExampleNoListenWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Counter counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false);

    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false):',
            ),
            Text(
              '${counter.count}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Increment"),
              onPressed: () => counter.increment(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because, while the widget that called `Provider.of` with `listen:false` did not want to rebuild, its parent forced it to.

In your example, when `Counter` changes, `MyHomePage` rebuilds and recreate the widget that specified `listen:false`, which in turn force it to rebuild too.

`MyHomePage` should specify `listen: false` too here.

Comment: Thanks Remi for the quick response. That makes sense and after changing the code as suggested it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

`listen: false` necessary to be able to call Provider.of inside [State.initState] or the create method of providers.

`listen: true`, latter value changes will trigger a new [State.build] to widgets, and [State.didChangeDependencies] for [StatefulWidget].

Answer (score 3):

What Remi suggested is a working approach (hack).
But I believe the better way in this case will be to remove the call
Counter counter = Provider.of(context); from the MyHomePageClass. That call is polluting the scope of your Counter object. 
As suggested by flutter.io , [It is best practice to put your Consumer widgets as deep in the tree as possible](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). As you did in the ExampleProviderWidget(),            ExampleConsumerWidget(),ExampleNoListenWidget(). So make the floatingActionButton a separate widget class and have its own Provider.of(context).
And your MyHomePageClass will not have to call Provider.of.

Answer (score 1):

According to the link below

> https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#providerof

when listen is set false, it won’t cause this widget to rebuild when notifyListeners is called.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31313964)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
I/flutter (12384): MyApp build
I/flutter (12384): MyHomePage build
I/flutter (12384): ExampleProviderWidget build
I/flutter (12384): ExampleConsumerWidget build
I/flutter (12384): ExampleNoListenWidget build
Reloaded 1 of 524 libraries in 792ms.
I/flutter (12384): ExampleProviderWidget build
I/flutter (12384): ExampleProviderWidget build
I/flutter (12384): ExampleProviderWidget build
I/flutter (12384): ExampleProviderWidget build


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;
  int get count => _count;

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('MyApp build');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Provider Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Provider Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  Counter _counter = Counter();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('MyHomePage build');
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: _counter,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ExampleProviderWidget(),
              ExampleConsumerWidget(),
              ExampleNoListenWidget()
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => _counter.increment(),
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleProviderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('ExampleProviderWidget build');
    Counter counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context);

    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Provider.of<Counter>(context):',
            ),
            Text(
              '${counter.count}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleConsumerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('ExampleConsumerWidget build');
    return Consumer<Counter>(
      builder: (context, counter, _) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Consumer<Counter>(context):',
                ),
                Text(
                  '${counter.count}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ExampleNoListenWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('ExampleNoListenWidget build');
    Counter counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false);

    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false):',
            ),
            Text(
              '${counter.count}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Increment"),
              onPressed: () => counter.increment(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is the **absence of const** in creation of *Example...Widgets*.
Remember, all `ChangeNotifierProvider` children are observers for state changes notifications.

If **const** is not present, the engine starts creating new widgets for all `ChangeNotifierProvider` children, using their `build` method. This process goes down until all widgets have been created.

The problem is: *when a new widget is created a new context is also created*, and `build` will be called for wich one. As the creation occurs all the time, `build` will be always called, spite the previous *listen* configuration.

BUT, when a widget is const, the engine does not creates a new instance and `listen` status is preserved, avoiding calling `build` in answer to chenge notifications.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you say `Provider.of<Counter>(context,`, you should write `, listen: false)`.

```
Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false);
```

Comment: not whenever , It depends on the situation.

Answer (score -2):

from the code you have written, the **increment** method you are using in the **onPressed** method will not work, if you implement **listen: false**.