# How does the listen: false work in Flutter Providers?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I just started learning Flutter, and I'm going through the Udemy course "Flutter & Dart - The Complete Guide". In that course, there is a section about building a shopping app, which uses providers. In one instance of that app, where the user swipes to delete a product from the Cart page (or screen/route) with the help of the Dismissible widget, he uses a function inside the provider class, which takes a product ID, to delete the item from the cart.

Here is the thing that I don't understand. The Dismissible widget is connected to the provider via this code in the *onDismissed* property (which fires after the swipe):

```
Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).removeItem(productId);
```

And it all works just fine like this. But if you remove the listen parameter (hence turning it into it's default state which is true), then the **Dismiss animation** still takes place, but the *removeItem()* method doesn't work, and the cart still stays the same.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Check this link out and let me know it helps! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584334/understand-how-listen-false-works-when-used-with-providersometype-ofcontext

Comment: @QuestionableCoder well that wasn't entirely my question. I wasn't asking about having out of the ordinary rebuilds. I was asking about the code not working without listen: false.

Answer (score 0):

When we use listen: false we are telling to not rebuild the widget after we remove an item, but they know that we are removing an item so we don't need to listen any value here it's just doing the action of removing

Answer (score 0):

**I'll refer to the method `Provider.of(context, listen: true)` as `x` throughout this answer.**

`x` is expected to be used ONLY for properties of a `Widget` that is

- expected to change; and
- can be rebuilt. For example:

```
SizedBox(
  width: Provider.of<MyLogic>(context, listen: true).width,
)
```

When used this way, `x` will ONLY be called when the `context` owner is being built/rebuilt.

To ensure that it is being used properly, `x` performs a sanity check every time it is called, making sure that the owner of the `context` you passed is actually being built/rebuilt. When you call `x` from within your `onPressed` or whatever method it is you call it from, `x` sees that the `context` owner is not in the "build" phase, and throws this error.

There are a few more details to this, but you don't actually need to know more about it (especially you're just beginning) unless you want to contribute to the package, in which case you should read their [documentation](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/).

Side note: you can now use `context.watch()` and `context.read()` instead of `Provider.of()`.