# why we need to get keyword in while createing class with changenotifer in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am new in learning flutter and learning provider when I using Change notifier class then I create instance in class then why need to use getter or Listen Property to false if we can not do nothing from these 2 then got show error

Comment: Does [false works when used with Provider<SomeType>.of(context, listen: false)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58584334/10157127) answer your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.