# Is Provider.of(context, listen: false) equivalent to context.read()?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

```
// Are these the same?
final model = Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false); 
final model = context.read<Model>(); 

// Are these the same?
final model = Provider.of<Model>(context);
final model = context.watch<Model>();
```

Are they the same or aren't they? If they are, then why do I get this error when I use `read` inside the `build()` method, while `Provider.of()` works?

> Tried to use `context.read<Model>` inside either a `build` method or the `update` callback of a provider.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, they aren't the same.

You shouldn't use `read` inside the `build` method. Instead stick to the old is gold pattern:

```
final model = Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false);
```

`read` is used when you want to use the above pattern in a callback, for instance, when a button is pressed, then we can say they both are performing the same action.

```
onPressed: () {
  final model = context.read<Model>(); // recommended
  final model = Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false); // works too
}
```

Comment: now it would be interesting to know, why does the documentation recommend against using context.read() in a build method ....

Comment: @Wecherowski In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62434596/6753606) answer, Remi explains why `context.read` must not be used in build method. But I must say that I'm not convinced by it.

Answer (score 33):

`final model = context.read<Model>();`
This returns the Model without listening for any changes.

`final model = context.watch<Model>();`
This makes the widget listen for changes on the Model.

`final model = Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false);`
This works the same as `context.read<Model>();`

`final model = Provider.of<Model>(context);`
This works the same as `context.watch<Model>();`

**Recommendations:**
Use `context.read()`, `context.watch()` instead of `Provider.of()`.
**For more insights**, refer to [this](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#reading-a-value), [this](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/313#issuecomment-576156922) & [this](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/313#issuecomment-603947053).

Comment: I am sure you must have read the question carefully before answering. -1 from me, sorry!!!

Comment: The default value of listen = true when you do not specify in Provider.of(). If you want to get updated data, you must use a "watch" instead or "read".

Comment: First, I didn't ask about the default value of `listen`, second, I didn't want to get the updated data. I again suggest you to read the question carefully before answering. Thanks

Comment: I didn't though. Can you kindly share any example what you want to achieve and what you are getting currently? It seems the question can lead to some misunderstanding. If possible!

Comment: Well I am currently using FirebaseAuth as my model, when I use `Provider.of(...)` with `listen: false`, it works but when I use `read`, it fails.

Comment: I have added my own answer, you can take a look now.

Answer (score 4):

`context.read<T>()` internally returns `Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false)`.

For the moment, use whichever you think is best or the one you prefer.

This is the implementation of read in Provider:

```
extension ReadContext on BuildContext {
  T read<T>() {
    return Provider.of<T>(this, listen: false);
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it directly address OP's question.