# Why can't I use context.read in build(), but I can use Provider.of with listen: false?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

It's stated in the docs that these are the same, and `context.read` is just a shortcut for `Provider.of<x>(context, listen: false)`.
There's also an error in the console if I try to use `context.read` in a build method, but it doesn't explain the reason.

I also found this topic: [Is Provider.of(context, listen: false) equivalent to context.read()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257064/is-provider-ofcontext-listen-false-equivalent-of-context-read)
But it doesn't answer "why".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Provider.of(context, listen: false) equivalent to context.read()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257064/is-provider-ofcontext-listen-false-equivalent-to-context-read)

Comment: @iLoveFlutterDocs yes. I moved my additional question to the separate topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539885/flutter-provider-what-is-the-best-way-to-dispatch-the-action-properly

Answer (score 59, accepted):

- `context.read` is not allowed inside `build` because it is very dangerous to use there, and there are much better solutions available.
- `Provider.of` is allowed in `build` for backward-compatibility.

Overall, the reasoning behind why `context.read` is not allowed inside `build` is explained in [its documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ReadContext/read.html):

> **DON'T** call [read] inside build if the value is used only for events:
>
> ```dart
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>   // counter is used only for the onPressed of RaisedButton
>   final counter = context.read<Counter>();
>
>   return RaisedButton(
>     onPressed: () => counter.increment(),
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> While this code is not bugged in itself, this is an anti-pattern.
>   It could easily lead to bugs in the future after refactoring the widget
>   to use `counter` for other things, but forget to change [read] into [watch].
>
> **CONSIDER** calling [read] inside event handlers:
>
> ```dart
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>   return RaisedButton(
>     onPressed: () {
>       // as performant as the previous previous solution, but resilient to refactoring
>       context.read<Counter>().increment(),
>     },
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> This has the same efficiency as the previous anti-pattern, but does not
>   suffer from the drawback of being brittle.
>
> **DON'T** use [read] for creating widgets with a value that never changes
>
> ```dart
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>   // using read because we only use a value that never changes.
>   final model = context.read<Model>();
>
>   return Text('${model.valueThatNeverChanges}');
> }
> ```
>
> While the idea of not rebuilding the widget if something else changes is
>   good, this should not be done with [read].
>   Relying on [read] for optimisations is very brittle and dependent
>   on an implementation detail.
>
> **CONSIDER** using [select] for filtering unwanted rebuilds
>
> ```dart
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>   // Using select to listen only to the value that used
>   final valueThatNeverChanges = context.select((Model model) => model.valueThatNeverChanges);
>
>   return Text('$valueThatNeverChanges');
> }
> ```
>
> While more verbose than [read], using [select] is a lot safer.
>   It does not rely on implementation details on `Model`, and it makes
>   impossible to have a bug where our UI does not refresh.

Comment: Personally I'm using the combination of provider and mobx, thus there will be never any reaction based on the `provider watch mechanism`. 
These considerations just forces people like me to follow the patterns in a none sense manner.

Comment: However, I'm using the mobx just because it's not dependent on calling something like `notifyListeners` in its actions. If Provider provides the same ability, I would drop mobx_flutter!

Comment: It seems to me that the usability of Provider.of with listen true/false is superior to the usability of context.watch/read because the former works in all situations and is therefore easier to learn whereas the latter, while seeming slightly more compact and elegant, can't be used as freely. So, for what reason is context.read/watch recommended?

Comment: @SergeyMolchanovsky About one month after the comment I moved to GetX. Thanks for recommendation btw 

Comment: ```context.read<NewsCubit>().getNews();``` - This should happen when building the widgets. How to do it? That is, I cannot call it when the button is clicked

Comment: @HamedHamedi I'm disappointed in GetX. It's very buggy and non-performant. It doesn't have actions and computeds. So I got back to MobX.

Comment: @SergeyMolchanovsky It feels so nice we are yet exchanging experience here for years :D
I also left behind GetX or at least it is existed only for dependency injection. 
In the latest company I'm working in, we have a combination of flutter_modular, bloc cubits and provider, and I can say by far this is the most robust structure we can have with flutter and recently I implemented a bunch of tests and everything was align for it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you try to call context before the widget has finished building, to run your code after the widget has finished building provide your code to the post frame callback function.

For Example:

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    // your code in here
});
```