# Flutter Provider: what is the best way to dispatch the action properly?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

The question is related to my previous question: [Why can't I use context.read in build(), but I can use Provider.of with listen: false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432759/why-cant-i-use-context-read-in-build-but-i-can-use-provider-of-with-listen)
You said that an old `Provider.of<X>(context, listen: false)` syntax is unsafe. However, it works.

[image: It works]

I believe `fetchTransactions()` method won't change, so there's no need to watch it.

I can't use `context.read` because it's not in the closure and will throw the "don't use context.read in a build method" error.

I can't use `context.watch` or `context.select` with `FutureBuilder`, because it will cause an infinite rebuild loop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build. You have a bug  but you're not aware of it

Comment: @RémiRousselet so, is the correct way to do `context.read().fetchTransactions()` in the InitState() and to save it to the state variable, and to use this variable inside of FutureBuilder?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @RémiRousselet how can I force FutureBuilder to refresh? It used to be updated with new server data on each widget rebuild, but now it makes API call in InitState() once and never refetch anymore.

Comment: Change the Future passed to FutureBuilder with a setState or something similar