# I get The prefix 'value' can't be used here because it is shadowed by a local declaration

Tags: flutter, dart

When I am doing this:

[image]

I am getting an error that says: **'The prefix 'value' can't be used here because it is shadowed by a local declaration.'**

I have referred the following:
[Why can't I use context.read in build(), but I can use Provider.of with listen: false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432759/why-cant-i-use-context-read-in-build-but-i-can-use-provider-of-with-listen)

I did not understand much. Can someone please help me in simple terms what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: probably because of no space in `elseif`?

Comment: Yes that is it. Not sure how I have missed it. Thank you much. But what does the error shadowed by local declaration mean. I was not able to find any official references.

Comment: No problem. Probably, you need to take a little nap :).

Comment: Yes, beginner days are very fatiguing -:)

Comment: this answer probably help you about the shadowing means: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53734745/4758255 
though the error message is not related with it. Your IDE is just giving you a related one based on the code it see.

Answer (score 0):

The error is just because no space in **elseif**.

But not sure what does the error shadowed by local declaration mean. I was not able to find any official references.