# How can I fix context.read(xxx).state error? Or replace with anything

Tags: flutter

```
var submitData = {
      'beauticianId': context.read(selectedBeautician).state.docId,
      'beauticianName': context.read(selectedBeautician).state.name,
      'cityBook': context.read(selectedCity).state.name,
      //'name': context.read(selectedBeautician).state.name,
      'clinicAddress': context.read(selectedClinic).state.address,
      'clinicId': context.read(selectedClinic).state.docId,
      'clinicName': context.read(selectedClinic).state.name,
      'slot': context.read(selectedTimeSlot).state,
      'timeStamp': timeStamp,
      'time': '${context.read(selectedTime).state} - ${DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(context.read(selectedDate).state)}'
    };
```

I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. There's a lot of that errors since I used that lines a lot.

Comment: are you using provider state management?

Comment: yes, I'm using the provider state management.

Comment: Can u share the code of, let's say, `selectedBeautician`?

Comment: Also share the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so instead of using context.read(someProvider).state use this

```
Provider.of<someProvider>(context).state
```

Comment: The details is given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62434596/14466860 by @Rémi Rousselet

Comment: Will it affect anything if I'm using ConsumerWidget?

Comment: no it will not if something went wrong then let me know

Comment: I still cannot solve the problem, the error is still there.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: When I change to this Provider.of<someProvider>(context).state the of<someProvider> is the error

Comment: don't write exactly someProvider replace the someProvider with the provider you want to use for example selectedTime in the your code write like this Provider.of<selectedTime>(context).state

Comment: I did that already, but the .of<provider> line is having error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It says that the function 'of' isn't define. And the name 'selectedBeautician' isn't a type, so it can't be used as a type argument.

Comment: Can I have your telegram id?